# Forbid deleting of data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is it possible to add a rule to forbid deleting data from my firebase? Something like

```
".delete":false
```

Comment: You can probably prevent empty data from being written using a `.validate` rule. See line 34 of https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-advanced-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that `newData` exists with a `.write` rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".write": "newData.exists()"
    }
}
```

You can see some good example of this type of rules in the [Anonymous Chat Example in the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-advanced-example) (I based my answer on the fragment in lines 32-34).

Comment: Thanks! and thanks for removing [javascript] - adding it almost became my reflex :D